# irreducible representation of a $C^*$ algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose we have a $C^*$ algebra $A=\{(x_n)\in \prod M_n(\Bbb C),lim_n tr_n(x_n^*x_n)=0\}$.

If $B$ is any nonzero $C^*$-sub algebra of $A$,does there exist a finite dimensional irreducible representation of $B$?

Comment: That's not a C*-algebra ...

Comment: @YemonChoi: it's not an algebra, in the same way that the set of zero trace matrices in $M_n$ isn't an algebra (the product of two matrices with zero trace could have nonzero trace).

Comment: @NikWeaver Oh of course, somehow my brain mentally put in the trace-norm of $x_n$ rather than the trace itself

Comment: That makes more sense, and then I think you're right that it would be a C*-algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Irreducible representations are the building blocks. If there is a finite dimensional representation, there is a finite dimensional irrep.  Any C*-subalgebra of $A$, indeed any C*-subalgebra of $\prod M_n$, has plenty of finite dimensional representations, namely evaluation on the $n$th factor, for any $n$.

Comment: If $\phi$ is a finite representation of $A$,$B$ is a $C^*$ subalgebra of $A$,I think that there is a possibility that $\phi_{B}=0$

Comment: If $B$ is not zero then it has to contain some element which is nonzero on some factor. Evaluation on that factor will not be zero on $B$.

Comment: (Indeed, any nonzero element of $B$ will not be in the kernel of some finite dimensional irrep.)